# How can I find the location of the generated css file on aem

Tags: css, localhost, aem

How can I find the location of the generated css file on aem, windows computer?

The page source loads the css from here:

```
http://localhost:5502/etc/designs/project/all_clientlibs.css
```

Where would that be on my file disk (it is not in `etc/designs/project/all_clientlibs.css` where the codebase is, so I think it is somewhere else generated) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path `/etc/designs/project/all_clientlibs.css` points in the structure of CRX database, based on Oak open source framework, which is one of the base parts of AEM. Physically all this database data is stored in large `tar` files in `crx-quickstart\repository\segmentstore` folder of your AEM instance, where the jar is present. The AEM data is then not stored explicitly in your OS file system. Tar files and Oak are used by default however it is also possible to configure AEM with MongoDB database.

If you would like to access the CRX repository in filesystem way you can consider using [WebDAV Access](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/administer/content/webdav-access.html).